# Understanding VBA to connect to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I don't have a programming issue, my program works just fine with the patchwork of code I have put together, but I did want to ask if someone could help me understand some of that code. Specifically, the part that connects VBA to SQL. The code is below:

```vb
' Create a connection object.

Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection
Dim iCols As Integer

' Provide the connection string.

Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.

strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;" & "Data Source=CIWSQLXD0026\DEV;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;" & "Workstation ID=AUSL0335;Initial Catalog=CSB_ACTL_AEData"

'Now open the connection.
cnPubs.Open strConn

cnPubs.CommandTimeout = 0
```

I'm most interested in understanding the properties in the part below:

```vb
'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.

strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;" & "Data Source=CIWSQLXD0026\DEV;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;" & "Workstation ID=AUSL0335;Initial Catalog=CSB_ACTL_AEData"
```

Thanks in advance for any help! Sorry the coloring of the code is weird. Long time user, newbie poster.

Comment: That is a [connection string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_string)

Comment: That is an OLEDB connection string. It specifies the driver to use that is installed on your computer as well as the attributes that the driver requires in order to make a connection to your DB. [ConnectionStrings.Com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) is a good resource for putting these together for most databases.

Comment: Your syntax can be corrected with [syntax hints BTW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). I've done this for you now

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering what the properties in that are actually doing, like: Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; and Integrated Security=SSPI; and Persist Security Info=True;

Comment: Lastly, is it possible to just use, "Data Source=CIWSQLXD0026\DEV"? Checking out ConnectionStrings com. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA is a programming language, programming languages use libraries to do whatever it is that you are asking them to do. There is a library to copy text to the clipboard, a library to open an internet window and communicate between IE and your program, and so there is also a library to connect to a database. The two main used ones on VBA are ADODB and DAO. In your case you are using the ADODB. The line you are interested about is pretty much a set of parameters that are being sent to the SQL library to connect to the database. Think of it as a website URL. Here is the URL for google when i search for "SQL"

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS794US794&oq=SQL&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i60j69i61.599j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

You can see that it has many parameters, q=SQL is what i searched for, aqs=chrome is the client chrome that i am using. And many more that tells the server what to do and how to search for "SQL.

On the SQL connection string is the same, it has parameters that tells it where to connect and how.

```
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;" & "Data Source=CIWSQLXD0026\DEV;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;" & "Workstation ID=AUSL0335;Initial Catalog=CSB_ACTL_AEData"
```

Provider is the connection type, integrated security is the security protocol to use when connecting, Data Source is the location (like a web link), and so on.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, that helps. I think I do need to dig into the code and play around with it a bit more to get comfortable with it. It's interesting that the ConnectionStrings Com website suggests something much different and simpler than what I was expecting is needed to connect to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a connection string which contains all of the information needed to set up the connection to the database, including things like the data source, which type of security / settings should be used in the configuration